# How to transfer favorite pictures to a computer?

Tags: 8.1, lumia-520, pictures, transfer

I have a Nokia Lumia 520 and I have a lot of favorite "hearted" pictures that I want to transfer to my computer for backup purposes. I don't want to transfer all the pictures because there are way too many and I would want to avoid using OneDrive. How should I do this?
I have a Windows 10 PC.

Update: My phone runs windows phone 8.

Comment: Is your phone running Windows Phone 8 or Windows 10 Mobile?

Comment: Is it *just* the favourited photos that you want?

Comment: I think it's windows phone 8. And yes, just the favorite photos

Answer (score 3):

The heart equivalent on the desktop is 4 stars. All "hearted" or "favourited" photos from your mobile phone are shown under the Windows Desktop OS photos with a 4 star rating.

Connect your phone to your laptop/desktop computer, and navigate under the pictures folder to reveal all the pictures. Then, right click on the titles ribbon of Windows Explorer (Files), and select the Ratings column if its not selected. After that, you should be able to see a column of ratings, and click on it to sort the pictures according to their ratings. This will bring all the 4-starred (♥) photos to the top, which you can now select from the first one to the last one, and then copy them

[image]

Comment: You can also go to the View tab and select "Group by" -> Rating, then click on the subheading for four-star items to select them all at once.

Comment: In my PC there's no option to show ratings - https://ibb.co/d7my3v

Comment: @AnswerQuicklyPlease enable Menu bar on your PC from where you can select ratings. https://ibb.co/m4033v

Comment: I see what you're saying, I can do that on my PC but when I go to my phone's SD card through file explorer, all I get is this - https://ibb.co/gY8HVa No Ratings checkbox!

Comment: Anyone can help me on this one? @Indrek ,@kelvinelove ,@User5

Comment: @AnswerQuicklyPlease Looks like Windows thinks you're storing music files in that folder. Try this: right-click on blank space inside the folder (ie. not on any file) and select Properties. Go to the Customize tab and under "Optimize this folder for:" select "Pictures". No see if Rating is available.